# How do I kill a blocking thread? (Cannot check for interruption)

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, java-threads

I have a thread that is running a runnable with just one command, that will block forever:

```kotlin
mainRunnable = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        startClient();
     }
};
```

This is not a normal thread where I am doing something over and over again (this would be easy to stop), but a thread were the command is running constantly and is blocking execution of further code in the runnable. So I basically, cannot implement the stop I believe.

This one command startClient is running all the time, is there a way I could stop it using the Thread object?

Thank you!

Comment: No.  There isn't.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Seriously?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Is there any other way that I can run the blocking `startClient` and be able to stop it later?

Comment: Yes, seriously.  See e.g. [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) for recommendations.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thanks, I did notice it not working anymore. Do you if there is any other way that I can run the blocking startClient and be able to stop it later?

Comment: The link I just posted describes the viable approaches.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I think those approaches would work if my Thread would do something over and over again, so I can check if it was interrupted or if some variable was set. But my code is blocking "forever", so I don't know where I can/should check for interruption and how I can then stop the execution of the blocked method.

Comment: Blocking how? What happens inside `startClient`?

Comment: @TimMoore It's basically a native method loaded in through `System.loadLibrary` and its a P2P node written in rust. I meant blocking in a way that, as long as the P2P client doesn't stop (theres no reason for it to), it blocks further execution of code. If I were to put a print before and after `startClient` I would just see the first and then the logs from the node running.

Comment: FYI: That's not really what "block" means. The way to describe how `startClient()` behaves at the call site is to say, "it never returns," or we say, "it loops forever." When we say that a thread is "blocked," we usually mean that it is not doing _anything._ A thread that's blocked is waiting for some event caused by another thread or, waiting for something external to the process. A blocked thread cannot do anything at all until the event happens. If `startClient` does anything useful, then it must not be spending _all_ of its time blocked in that way.

Comment: Re, "[startClient is] a native method...written in rust." Do you build it from source? Are you allowed to change the source? Have you examined the source to see whether there is any thing that could happen that would make `startClient` return? (e.g., is there a "shutdown" method that could be called from another thread? ) If it's a "client," then it must be talking to something. Is there some message that the other party could send that shuts it down? If you build it from source, maybe you could add a "shutdown" capability.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Yeah it basically loops for-ever, I should probably look into stopping it from inside rust

Comment: Perhaps another option is to run the Rust code as a subprocess using `ProcessBuilder` instead of a thread. Then, that process can be killed by the parent by calling `destroy` on it (assuming that it responds to OS interrupt signals, or `destroyForcibly` on Java 8+ if not)