# How to run blocking method async, but be able to stop it later?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, blocking, completable-future

I have a method called `runClient` that is blocking, basically it never ends. My first instinct was to put it into a Thread, but I can't stop it because `stop()` is deprecated, and I cannot check for an interrupt if the method is always blocking.

Is there some way to run it async, and then be able later to stop/destroy the execution of the method?

Comment: You tagged completable future, which is indeed what you could use. Check CompletableFuture.runAsync

Comment: @MatteoNNZ Nice, will give it a go

Comment: Have you already read: [How to properly stop the Thread in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961714/how-to-properly-stop-the-thread-in-java) ?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ Do you know how I can stop the completable-future from executing?

Comment: @Markusbug: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#cancel-boolean- .  (This won't necessarily stop the work from running, through any mechanism other than interruption.  It does not solve your real problem.)

Comment: Isn’t this essentially the same question you posted earlier? https://stackoverflow.com/q/74450934/29470

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I kill a blocking thread? (Cannot check for interruption)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74450934/how-do-i-kill-a-blocking-thread-cannot-check-for-interruption)

Comment: @Markusbug you have a .cancel() method on the instance of CompletableFuture that is returned by the runAsync

Comment: @LouisWasserman it does not even stop the work via interruption, as stated explicitly.